# Gurobi License verification Error as invalid

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, licensing, gurobi

I am seeing the below error in Gurobi manager UI after configuring a WEBFLOATCS license for the Gurobi Compute deployed in GKE.

License Status - Invalid
Error - Too many sessions, 1 active sessions for a baseline of 1

The license → info section in Gurobi manager has the correct node id and web lic details which means the lic configuration is correct

Can you pls help?

Comment: If a node has an INVALID license, you can run the command to learn more: **grbcluster node licenses**. The node licenses command can be used at any time to check the validity and attributes of licenses on all the nodes of the cluster (**expiration date, distributed limit, etc.**).

Comment: Hi @SaiChandiniRouthu I see this error when I run "grbcluster node licenses" - fatal : Cannot create client from configuration

Comment: You need to  **grb_rsm** install and run, Refer to the [service manual](https://www.gurobi.com/wp-content/plugins/hd_documentations/documentation/9.5/remoteservices.pdf) page no 25 & 26 for more details.

Comment: Refer to this  [Cluster Manager Server](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/remoteservices/cluster_manager_server__rs.html) (grb_rsm) for more information

Comment: @SaiChandiniRouthu we are using the containerized gurobi-compute and gurobi-manager components. I believe it comes out of the box with grb_rsm installation. In Gurobi Manager UI I see the lic identified but not sure why it has Invalid status with  error "Too many sessions, 1 active sessions for a baseline of 1"

Comment: Refer to this [gurobi optimization](https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/remoteservices/verification2.html)

Comment: Have you resolved your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This error indicates that you are already running another session with the same WLS license and since your baseline is limited to 1, you cannot have two sessions at the same time.